# Can Windows Store apps be compiled as x86 instead of AnyCPU?

Tags: windows-8, x86, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, anycpu

I have some .NET code that I am looking into porting into being a Windows Store app.

This code does a few different things and one of the things it does has a dependency on being compiled as x86 instead of AnyCPU.

Is this going to be a problem? Can a Metro app be compiled as x86 and still be distributed on the Windows Store? Is being compiled as x86 going to stop it from being able to run in Windows RT? Would I have to come up with a version without this subset of functionality to run in Windows RT? If I can get the code into its own assembly can I just have the Windows RT version not use it? (so, the main executable is AnyCPU and this one assembly is x86).

Comment: This may be a good question to ask in the developer chat tonight in the windows 8 chat room:  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17195/windows-8-developers-chat?cb=1

Answer (score 5):

> Can a Metro app be compiled as x86 and still be distributed on the Windows Store?

Yes. However, it would only be installable for x86 installations.

> Is being compiled as x86 going to stop it from being able to run in Windows RT?

Since Windows RT is designed to run only on ARM CPUs, compiling for x86 will stop it from being able to run on Windows RT.

> Would I have to come up with a version without this subset of functionality to run in Windows RT? If I can get the code into its own assembly can I just have the Windows RT version not use it?

You could use conditional compilation symbols to include/exclude functionality as required in your code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6587823/61385 shows an example of how to do this.

Comment: I guess what I'm really asking is - would I need to put out two versions? I see how conditional statements can get me down to one codebase but is it possible to release one version that can exclude the x86-dependent feature when run on RT? If so, would this make it past Microsoft's review staff and get onto the store?

Comment: Yes, I suppose this is possible. When you're building the apps, you specify what architectures you want to support (x86, x64 and ARM). This will create the corresponding files to be uploaded. Whichever of the files you upload will be the supported platforms which show up in the Store. Whether or not the review staff will accept it is another matter entirely. When submitting your app for certification, there's a field for including notes to the testers, so I guess you could use that to provide details regarding the difference in functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Just compile whatever libs you need and when you upload to app store just upload the one you want to. Check your apppackages folder and look for the .appxupload files.